# Java binary search tree - incorrectly working insert method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've a binary search tree homework in Java where I was given complete Tree and Node classes and a SearchTree class in which I'm to complete the search and insert methods. The search is supposed to return the value of the node corresponding the searched key.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iy1BL2nv) is the Tree class and [here](http://pastebin.com/mVnPU8Yd) the Node class. My search and insert methods are below.

It seems I'm getting close, but test insert of key 0 and value 2 into Tree[Node[0,1,null,null]] results in Tree[Node[0,1,null,null] rather than the correct Tree[Node[0,2,null,null]]. What am I not understanding here?

```
public static Object search(Tree tree, int key) {
    Node x = tree.getRoot();
    while (x != null) {
        if (key == x.getKey()) {
            return x.getValue();
        }
        if (key < x.getKey()) {
            x = x.getLeft();
        } else {
            x = x.getRight();
        }            
    }
    return null;
}

public static void insert(Tree tree, int key, Object value) {
    if (tree.getRoot() == null) {
        tree.setRoot(new Node(key, value));
    }
    Node juuri = tree.getRoot();
    while (juuri != null) {
        if (key == juuri.getKey()) {
            return;
        } else if (key < juuri.getKey()) {
            if (juuri.getLeft() == null) {
                juuri.setLeft(new Node(key, value));
                return;
            } else {
                juuri = juuri.getLeft();
            }
        } else {
            if (juuri.getRight() == null) {
                juuri.setRight(new Node(key, value));
                return;
            } else {
                juuri = juuri.getRight();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue I am seeing is that key values in your tree are unique. In this if statement you leave your `insert` method without adding a node if you see that the key is already in the tree.

```
 if (key == juuri.getKey()) { 
      return;
 }
```

In your example (if I understand it right) 0 is already in the tree so nothing changes when inserting 0 again. Based on your example, I am assuming you want to do an update on a node if the key is the same. So this code would do it.

```
if (key == juuri.getKey()) {
     juuri.setValue(value);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Ah, the very thing that was missing. Thank you, greatly appreciated.